# what is the use of ROS_INFO_NAMED and ROS_INFO_THROTTLE?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i got the error while using ROS_INFO_THROTTLE..SO for this we have any need to use different header files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321631/what-is-the-use-of-ros_info_named-and-ros_info_throttle?/) by [roslearnersai](https://answers.ros.org/users/40990/roslearnersai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-09-14**:
This doesn't explain `NAMED` fully (does the log end up in rosout/stdout for instance?) but the explanation for `THROTTLE` is good http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-09-14**:
If you got a compilation error you are likely using an older version of ros that doesn't have support for throttle (kinetic or earlier?)

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-09-14**:
This answer #q209522 says the name variable overrides the node name (or is it appended to the node name with a dot as the wiki suggests?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is an example of ROS_INFO_THROTTLE. It prints at most once per second.

```
ROS_INFO_THROTTLE (1.0, "Waiting for startup to finish");
```

Here is an example of ROS_INFO_NAMED. It logs to a logger named `my_package`:

```
ROS_INFO_NAMED("my_package", "Info log from my library.");
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roslearnersai](https://answers.ros.org/users/40990/roslearnersai/) on 2019-04-23**:
thank u ahendrix,
but i havce a doubt..
how ros_info_named is useful..and where its log file is stored..and for what purpose this ros_info_named is used..please explain..if we are using _throttle ...is there any need to add header files..

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-04-23**:
All of these macros are included if you `#include <ros/ros.h>` .

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-04-23**:
The named loggers go to the same file, but they have separate verbosity level that can be adjusted with `rqt_logger_level` ( http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_logger_level?distro=melodic )
So for example, you can use a named logger and set it to show DEBUG messages, even though the rest of your logging is still set to only show INFO or WARN.